# Unity Meta Files and Version Control

Tags: git, unity-game-engine, version-control, bitbucket, sourcetree

*I asked a similar question the other day, but i think this is different enough to make it worth another question*

I am currently using BitBucket and Source tree with my project, here is my git ignore.

EDIT* NEW GITIGNORE.
[image]

EDIT* File Structure.
[image]

My issue is that when I switch PC and pull as soon as i open the project, without doing anything it gives me about 1000 meta files to commit and a project settings file and a c sharp assembly file, surely this cant be right. Thoughts?

I do have force text enabled and i do have meta files visible.

Thanks Everyone.

**EDIT**

Here is a snapshot of the meta files.

[image]

Comment: I suggest adding these files to your .gitignore file. Anything that is generated by your build system should be ignored and not added to version control.

Comment: What do the paths to these 1000 meta files look like? For the record, the meta files should not be ignored and should be on your repo online.

Comment: @andeart Added a snapshot of the files.

Comment: It looks like you have a folder called 'Not a Nightmare' inside your project's root, which isn't being ignored.

Comment: @andeart that is the unity project folder.

Comment: Well, if your gitignore has `/Library/`, it is not going to ignore `Not a Nightmare/Library/`. I suggest removing the leading slash (but that would look for Library anywhere, which might act up), or restructuring your project so that your Unity project is the root.

Answer (score 2):

My guess is that these files are indeed in your repository (perhaps they were added before you updated your `.gitignore`), that they contain `CRLF` line endings, and that on your new PC `git core.autocrlf` returns `true`. If that is indeed the case, then git plans to convert all those `CRLF`s into `LF`s, and thus considers your local copy "different" than what is in the repo. Try setting `core.autocrlf` to false to stop git from doing that. If that fixes it, a good idea would be to add the following to your `.gitattributes` file:

```
* -text
```

That will disable such end of line processing no matter what machine the repo is on in the future.

Answer (score 0):

As I posted in the comment above:
If your gitignore has `/Library/`, it is not going to ignore `Not a Nightmare/Library/` and its contained files. You could try removing the leading slash, but I suggest restructuring your project so that your Unity project is the root.

Example:

[image]

I hope that helps!

Comment: Edited original post to show a new git ignore i have tried and the file structure which it was already like with the old git ignore.